# twitter bootstrap form inline stretch

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've got a inline form with Bootstrap 2.0.1 - this form has 3 labels and 3 dropdowns...

What I am trying to do is stretch the dropdowns in a way that the first one is to the left and the third one is to the right of the containing div....I can do this via some float left and right but I was wondering if there is something like this built-in already?

Thoughts?

The code looks like this

```html
<form id="frmOptions" method="post" class="form-inline">
   <label>Option 1:</label>
   <select>---</select>

   <label>Option 2:</label>
   <select>---</select> 

   <label>Option 3:</label>
   <select>---</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want 3 columns in your form, with one select in each column?

Comment: yes and they should stretch to use full space of parent div

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the fluid width section of the Scaffolding page of the Twitter Bootstrap documentation: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html
You will need to take advantage of the `span` and `row-fluid` classes to next your select controls in a fluid width form.

Here's an example:

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<form id="frmOptions" method="post" class="well form-inline span12">

     <div class="row-fluid">   
        <div id="formLeft" class="span3">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label for="select1" class="control-label">Option 1:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="select1">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
            </div>      
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="formCenter" class="span3">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label for="select2" class="control-label">Option 2:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="select2">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
            </div>      
          </div>    
        </div>

        <div id="formRight" class="span3">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label for="select3" class="control-label">Option 3:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="select3">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
            </div>      
          </div>    
    </div>   

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the above example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CdNef/

Here is the same example with the labels inline, rather than on top of the dropdown: http://jsfiddle.net/gbumP/

Comment: I've noticed the first example on jsfiddle has overlapping selectors. Was this how it looked originally? If not do you know how to fix it as this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: The select elements overlap because they have fixed widths (a Bootstrap default).  A quick fix here is to set a percentage width for the selects in css: `select {width:99%;}`